# How to limit rows returned in a SQL query to a ServiceNow database

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, servicenow

I read that ServiceNow uses mySQL, but the LIMIT command is giving me a syntax error when I try to connect via OPENQUERY in SSMS:

e.g.

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'SELECT * FROM incident LIMIT 100')`

Have also tried

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'SELECT TOP 100 FROM incident')`

and

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'SELECT * FROM incident WHERE ROWNUM < 100')`

but neither of those work either.

Comment: Please add the error message in full.

Comment: The syntax `SELECT * FROM incident LIMIT 100` is the one that MySQL supports. The second one is for Sybase or SQL Server, and the last one is for Oracle.

Comment: Full error:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW" returned message "[SN][ODBC ServiceNow driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Syntax error in SQL statement. syntax error line 1 at or after token <100>.[10179]".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM incident LIMIT 100" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW".